# cannot resolve symbol when read source code with android studio

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I try to read source code with android studio, and there are many **cannot resolve symbol** errors in it. Those errors include unsolved class(for example `android.util.MathUtils`, `android.annotation.NonNull` and `com.google.android.collect.Lists`) and variables(even I could see some of variable is defined in source).

To fix this issue, i import necessary dependencies in *build.gradle*, but it's useless.

what should i do to fix this issue.

Comment: Can you list dependencies that you put and some of the unresolved symbols?

Comment: Please list of dependencies and symbols which compiler says cannot resolve. so we can help you.

Comment: I create a new project and check source code of `ListView` with <i>go to declaration</i>. The project could be built successfully, but  there are lots of  errors in `ListView.java`, this makes me could not read it with <i>go to declaration</i>, <i>find usage</i> etc.